# Sitecore item deserialization is slow / triggering cache-clear

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Problem: when using the `Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager`to de-serialize serialized items into Sitecore 8, my caches get cleared. This shouldn't be so, since I call it with option `DisableEvents = true` like this:

```cs
var options = new Sitecore.Data.Serialization.LoadOptions(masterDb);
options.ForceUpdate = true;
options.DisableEvents = true;

using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.LoadItem(itemPath, options);
}
```

Still, though, cache is being cleared - with debugging enabled, I get this:

> 36956 19:32:31 INFO  Loading item from path
>   /master/sitecore/templates/SomeFolder/SomeItem.item.
>
> 36956 19:32:34 WARN  All
>   caches have been cleared. This can decrease performance considerably.
>
> 36956 19:32:34 DEBUG All caches have been cleared. Stack trace:
>      at
>   System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
>   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()    at
>   Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.ClearAllCaches()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.<.cctor>b__1(SerializationFinishedEvent
>   event)    at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseEvent(Object event,
>   Type eventType, EventContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.DeserializationFinished(String
>   databaseName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Marek's answer made me realize, I was saying something wrong. I will leave my original proposed answer intact to not cause confusion. But to sum up, calling the `LoadItem`method *with* option `DisableEvents`works as expected. Only does it - to make up for the lack of appropriate events getting fired - trigger `Manager.DeserializationFinished(...)` which in turn (at least per my default Sitecore 8 setup) calls `CacheManager.ClearAllCaches()`.

My wrong conclusion was triggered by the fact, that the `CacheManager.ClearAllCaches()`method is called using Sitecore's own * EventProvider* - so, as Marek points out - this is an unfortunate coincidence / clash of naming.

Actually, triggering `CacheManager.ClearAllCaches()` is what I wanted to avoid. So I guess somehow this "workaround" makes my deserialization faster (because it doesn't clear all the caches for each execution).

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

Ok, so I went to town and eventually discovered this, disassembling `Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.LoadItem(...)`method (note: this is Sitecore **core stuff** (with my comments)):

```cs
public static Item LoadItem(string path, LoadOptions options)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(path, "path");
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) options, "options");
      if (!options.DisableEvents) <-------------------------- HERE IS THE BUG
        return Manager.DoLoadItem(path, options);
      Item obj;
      using (new EventDisabler())
        obj = Manager.DoLoadItem(path, options);
      //This next line fires the events - but to get here, DisableEvents must be true.
      Manager.DeserializationFinished(Manager.GetTargetDatabase(path, options));
      return obj;
    }
```

This looks like a bug. "If not options.DisableEvents return". There's one too many "not"?

The workaround is simply to set

```cs
options.DisableEvents = false;
```

Setting it to `false`disables the events listening at `SerializationFinishedEvent`, in this case a handler, that triggers `Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.ClearAllCaches()` as hinted by the stack-trace. Even though it seems like it should be the other way around.

Comment: Sorry @FrederikStruck-Schøning but you're not right. See my answer below.

Comment: I realize, you are right. I've answered you in your "answer".

Comment: @MarekMusielak I've made an update in the beginning of my own "answer" to reflect, what you have helped me realize :)

Answer (score 2):

Frederik, in your answer you pasted disassembled code of the `LoadItem` method and you added comments in the lines, where you thought there was a bug:

```cs
// QUOTE FROM THE AUTHOR OF THE QUESTION, Frederik Struck-Schøning
public static Item LoadItem(string path, LoadOptions options)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(path, "path");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) options, "options");
    if (!options.DisableEvents) <-------------------------- HERE IS THE BUG
      return Manager.DoLoadItem(path, options);
    Item obj;
    using (new EventDisabler())
        obj = Manager.DoLoadItem(path, options);
    //This next line fires the events - but to get here, DisableEvents must be true.
    Manager.DeserializationFinished(Manager.GetTargetDatabase(path, options));
    return obj;
}
```

And then you explained why you think this code is incorrect.

Actually, **it's exactly the opposite way to what you wrote**.

When you deserialize items without `DisableEvents` set to **false**, all the caches are updated automatically by `item:saved` and other events.

If you tell Sitecore to disable all the events, caches would never be refreshed. That's the reason why Sitecore executes `ClearAllCaches` after the items are deserialized. It's unfortunate that in the stack trace you see name "event". All Sitecore events, like `item:added`, `item:created`, `item:saved` etc are not executed. There is only 1 event which is executed to notify your current instance and remote Sitecore instances and this event is `SerializationFinishedEvent` (in its local and remote version).

So this is **not** a **Sitecore** bug, it's naming issue rather. It might be misleading, but it all works as expected. Instead of executing series of events every time item is saved, updated, renamed and so on, there is only one notification after the `DoLoadItem` method is finished.

Comment: Hi Marek, thanks for your answer. I realize, you are right: if `DisableEvents = true`, indeed the `EventDisabler` is used when loading the item. I was too focused on the DeserializationFinished call, that in turn calls the `CacheManager.ClearAllCaches()` method. I use the `LoadItem` method many times within a short period of time, thus the `ClearAllCaches()` call gets expensive. Can you think of a way to disable the events *and* not call `ClearAllCaches()`? Can I somehow remove this event-handler?